# How can I run a a Powershell command in VBA which contains "$env:UserName"?

Tags: vba, powershell

I have the following macro which works just fine:

```
Private Sub Macro()
    Dim ExecuteCommand As String
    ExecuteCommand = "PowerShell -Command ""& 'C:\Program Files\R\R-4.2.2\bin\Rscript.exe' 'C:\Users\MyUser\Cool Calculations.R'"""
    Shell ExecuteCommand 
End Sub
```

What I want to do however, is to replace the name "MyUser" with `$env:UserName` instead.

However this macro does not seem to work:

```
Private Sub Macro()
    Dim ExecuteCommand As String
    ExecuteCommand = "PowerShell -Command ""& 'C:\Program Files\R\R-4.2.2\bin\Rscript.exe' 'C:\Users\$env:UserName\Cool Calculations.R'"""
    Shell ExecuteCommand 
End Sub
```

I have tried to run the command manually in PowerShell and it works correctly:

```
& "C:\Program Files\R\R-4.2.2\bin\Rscript.exe" "C:\Users\$env:UserName\Cool Calculations.R"
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong when trying to add `$env:UserName` in my macro?

Comment: Change `'C:\Users\$env:UserName\Cool Calculations.R'` to `""C:\Users\$env:UserName\Cool Calculations.R""`. In PowerShell: single-quotes = verbatim strings; double-qoutes = expandable strings

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Unfortunately this did not seem to work either: `PSCommand = "PowerShell -Command ""& 'C:\Program Files\R\R-4.2.2\bin\Rscript.exe' ""C:\Users\$env:UserName\Cool Calculations.R"""""`

Comment: I tested solution of Mathias, worked.

Comment: @jacouh, it doesn't, because the path has spaces and must be double-quoted, and without ``\``-escaping, the double quotes are effectively removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- As Mathias points out, only `"..."` strings ([expandable strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings)) perform variable expansion (interpolation) in Powershell; `'...'` strings ([verbatim strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#single-quoted-strings)) do not.
- Thus you must pass what PowerShell *ultimately* see as a `"C:\Users\$env:UserName\Cool Calculations.R"` argument (as an aside: consider simplifying to `"$env:USERPROFILE\Cool Calculations.R"`); since you're calling from VBA, this requires:

  - Using `""...""` to embed `"` chars. inside a VBA `"..."` string...
  - *and* `\`-escaping for the sake of `powershell.exe`, the [Windows PowerShell CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) (which receives its `-Command` argument as a `"..."` string, so any `"` chars. to be retained as part of the command must be escaped)
  - That is, you need something like the following (sic; spaces added for readability)

    ```vb
    " PowerShell -Command "" & '...' \""...\"" "" "
    ```

Specifically:

```vb
Private Sub Macro()
    Dim ExecuteCommand As String
    ExecuteCommand = "PowerShell -Command ""& 'C:\Program Files\R\R-4.2.2\bin\Rscript.exe' \""C:\Users\$env:UserName\Cool Calculations.R\"""""
    Shell ExecuteCommand 
End Sub
```

Comment: That was it! the \ for escape characters was the missing link to get it to work. Thanks and thanks for the additional explanation and `$env:USERPROFILE`. I did not know this existed.

Answer (score 0):

mklement0's response is very elegant, tested working. But I tested the command without escape, that seems not required under Windows Powershell, as Mathias suggested, it works also. I replaced `Rscript.exe` that I have not installed, by `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet like this:

```
Sub RunPSFromVba()
    Dim ExecuteCommand As String
    'ExecuteCommand = "PowerShell -Command ""& 'C:\Program Files\R\R-4.2.2\bin\Rscript.exe' 'C:\Users\$env:UserName\Cool Calculations.R'"""
    ExecuteCommand = "PowerShell -NoExit -Command ""& 'Get-ChildItem' ""C:\Users\$env:UserName\Downloads"""""
    Shell ExecuteCommand
End Sub
```

With `PowerShell -NoExit`, I keep the PowerShell Window alive after execution, I got this screenshot:

[image]

Hope this will also help.